# Django Website <button /> tags do not work on firefox web browser

Tags: javascript, django, firefox

I have created a read more js event for my django app. To fire the event there is a button with onclick="myFunction()" in the button tag of the html.

The issue I am having is on Firefox. I can't click any buttons or any links on the django app/website. AT ALL. This is only the case for my django app, other website works perfectly. When clicking the button nothing comes up in the console. It is almost as if the browser doesnt even see the button or any menu links.

Safari and Chrome everything works normally.

Thank you for your time and responses!

Answer (score 0):

The [MDN Documentation for the Button element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) states that `[...] both the starting and ending tag are mandatory.`

Other browsers may be more flexible.

Have you tried changing your source from `<button onclick="..." />` to `<button onclick="..."></button>`?

Comment: This was the issue. I read the documentation you attached. I was not finishing the tag fully. It is working now. Thank You!